# Is the INVOICING.INVOICE.SCHEDULED automatically created?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I've implemented `PayPal` gateway in my application, and I'm looking for a way to send a notification to my customer when an upcoming renewal is coming.

Unfortunately in the documentation I didn't find a depth explaination about `INVOICING.INVOICE.SCHEDULED` but I'm guessing should be the same as `invoice.upcoming` of `Stripe` which is triggered when a recurring payment is going to be renewed.

My question is: `INVOICING.INVOICE.SCHEDULED` is sended by `PayPal` automatically when a recurring payment is going to be renewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoicing and Subscriptions are two separate PayPal products.  I would not expect an Invoicing webhook in relation to a Subscription recurring payment.

The subscription webhooks are listed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

If you are looking for one that happens "in advance" of a scheduled payment, I am not aware of one.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, so you confirm that I can't know if a subscription is renewed? 'cause I need to update the next billing cycle inside my database. How would you handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by renewed? Subscriptions happen on a cycle. You will be notified when every cycle's payment occurs, by a PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED

Comment: So I guess when the `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` the webhook `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.RENEWED` is automatically called, right?

Comment: For questions like this it's useful to consult the list of webhook event names: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions .  BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.RENEWED is not one of the listed webhook event names

Comment: `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.RENEWED` seems to be missing in the link you gave: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

Comment: The doc is up to date. That webhook name doesn't exist as part of the subscriptions API; for payment notifications, use PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED